# Couchbase lite data storing path

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am using couchbase lite for my **Windows application**, I want to know the place where Document created by code are going to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

The location is determined by the JavaContext you pass when you create a new Manager object.

The default is a subdirectory named "cblite", or you can pass a String arg when you create the JavaContext instance.

If the path you supply is not absolute, the location is relative to the working directory of the application.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 you can specify the location of a database when you connect to it.
According to the docs:

The DatabaseConfiguration.Database property Gets or sets the directory to use when creating or opening the data.

So when you create the Database object, the constructor 
"Creates a database with a given name and database configuration. If the configuration is null then the default configuration will be used. If the database does not yet exist, it will be created."

```
var database = new Database("mydb", new DatabaseConfiguration(){Database="mylocation/dbname"});
```

This is rough code but you get the idea.

If you do not specify a directory path when you create a db then it goes in a default directory in your local user space, for Windows this is explained in this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943249/where-does-couchbase-lite-store-its-files-on-windows)