# where does couchbase lite store its files on windows?

Tags: c#, windows, couchbase-lite

[This page](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/manager/index.html) shows where the data is stored on various platforms, but not on windows. Where does CouchDB Lite create the directory and files for windows?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but for Couchbase default location is Windows C:\Program Files\couchbase\server\var\lib\couchbase\data  according to http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/admin-datafiles.html I know this not for Lite version. Give it a try

Comment: nope, no couchbase folder, as couchbase lite doesn't use an installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Manager` object contains a path to a root directory where databases are stored (each db is put inside a sub directory) and the `Database` object contains a path to the sub directory.

The default root directory appears to be: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local`
and databases are in sub directories such as `testdb2.cblite2` where the first part of the name is the name of the database you gave it in your code.

Comment: To add on, the shortcut to that directory is `%LOCALAPPDATA%`