# How to view the data (document) stored in Couchbase Lite?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, couchbase-lite

I want to develop a mobile app using Cordova, ionic 2 and Couchbase Lite (for offline data capability in mobile). When the data is stored, where the data is stored physically (physical location). How to open and view the documents stored.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Lite stores your data in a SQLite database. The [wiki](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/wiki#tools) offers 2 tools to view your data:

- [CouchbaseLiteViewer](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer)
- [Android dbinspector](https://github.com/infinum/android_dbinspector)

---

Edit: Regarding the actual location of the SQLite database files:

According to the [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/manager/index.html) a so called `Manager` creates a directory to store your databases in. Here's a paste of the locations by platform:

- Android: The directory is the location returned by the Android Context object's `getFilesDir()`.
- iOS: `Application Support/CouchbaseLite/`
- macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/com.example.YourAppBundleID/CouchbaseLite/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. These tools are helpful for iOS developers and android native app developers. But I am using Cordova and ionic 2 to develop the cross platform app. I don't have bundle.gradle file so that I can include Dbinspector. What is the physical location of the db?

Comment: I added some more information about the actual location of the database files. Hope it helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016745/couchbase-lite-data-storing-path?rq=1 might also be of interest...

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. In the above link, discussion is about windows mobile, not the required one.

Comment: I also edited my original answer. See it for the information regarding iOS and Android...

Comment: I am using Cordova, ionic 2 so I can't create a manager and the method getFilesDir();.

Comment: Depending on your Android version the path returned could be `/data/data/{your package name}/files`... See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775949/what-path-does-getapplicationcontext-getfilesdir-return)